# If there a valid way to change text styles within a hyperlink?

Tags: html, xhtml, xhtml-1.0-strict

I am trying to validate my code as follows:

```
<ul class="work">
    <li>
        <a href="work1.html"> <img src="images/work_1.png" alt="Work 1 Logo" /> <h4>Lorem ipsum doler sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.</h4> Work 1 </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="work2.html"> <img src="images/work_2.png" alt="Work 2 Logo" /> <h4>Lorem ipsum doler sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.</h4> Work 2 </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="work3.html"> <img src="images/work_3.png" alt="Work 3 Logo" /> <h4>Lorem ipsum doler sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.</h4> Work 3 </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The problem I am facing, of course, is that block-level elements (h4) should not be inside inline elements (a).  Is there any XHTML 1.0 Strict valid way which will allow me to see the same effect that I see right now with this code?
The unique aesthetic benefit I get by having the (h4) within the (a) is the fact that there are two different text styles both being affected by the same anchor.  It actually looks quite good on my page!

Comment: Any reason not to just use styleing and spans to achieve the visual effects that you are after? You might have to manually recreate the styles of the h4 but it would be valid XHTML...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your `h4` to `span` and give them the same styles.

```
<ul class="work">
    <li>
        <a href="work1.html"> <img src="images/work_1.png" alt="Work 1 Logo" />
        <span>Lorem ipsum doler sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
        Work 1</a>
    </li>
etc.
```

Comment: Thank you!  An obvious answer which I clearly overlooked.  :)